# Closure of Integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Fellow Mathers, is the fact that the Integers are closed under addition and multiplication...

> ∀ a,b ∈ **Z** , a + b = c where c ∈ **Z**
>
> ∀ a,b ∈ **Z** , ab = c where c ∈ **Z**

...universal axioms, theorems, dependent upon the axioms your using, etc?

Thank you. - New Math Guy

Comment: I think it is axiomatic.  I think that is how we define integers in the first place.  $1$ is an integer. Addition is closed under integers... now go nuts.  The "integers" is everything you can come up with and no more  (well actually that is how we come up with natural numbers... also with the stipulation that $a + 1\ne a$.)

Comment: 10-4, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @fleablood Is multiplication closure also axiomatic in the same way?

Comment: @BallBoy: it depends on exactly how you define/construct the integers.

Comment: If you define multiplication as $m\times n = \underbrace{n+ n+ n+ n+....+n}$ then no.  That follows that it is closed by induction.  Although induction is usually an axiom.  Notice: I'm skirting around and avoiding I am working with the Peano Postulates.  Which are not the *only* way to define the integers but it is one of the better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends sensitively on your definitions. Assuming a given definition of $\mathbb{N}$, here is a perspective from which both are theorems. Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, defined by: 
$$(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff a+d = c+b.$$
Then, for each $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$, we can define the *equivalence class*, $$E_{a,b} = \{(c,d) \text{ such that } (c,d) \sim (a,b)\}.$$
It is not hard to see that the set of all such equivalence classes consists of:

- $E_{a+1,1}$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ (the so-called *positive integers*),
- $E_{1, a+1}$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ (the so-called *negative integers*), and
- $E_{1,1}$ ("zero")

and no other elements. We can then define $\mathbb{Z}$ to be the set of all these equivalence classes. You can define
$$E_{a,b} + E_{c,d} = E_{a+c, b+d}$$
well now it's totally totally obvious that this is closed, and the other properties of addition are theorems.

On the other hand, you might can imagine giving someone only "part of the definition", such as telling them that $+$ is commutative, and telling them how to add positive numbers to integers (leaving the rest to be worked out). Then the fact that this uniquely defines a binary operation on $Z$ is a *theorem*, and some of the other properties are definitions.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

They are not theorems but axioms of the integers. In other words, the closure laws for addition and multiplication are among the fundamental statements about integers and real numbers that we assume to be true.

Comment: Sweet, thanks man

Comment: Np. if you are satisfied with your answers, please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!